# create a black image with specified size, depth, channels with opencv cv2 module

Tags: opencv

I want to create a black image with cv2 module in opencv. Python is prefered. It seems I should use numpy to do it but  I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code will create a blank Mat of size (500,500) with 8 bit pixels:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = np.zeros((500, 500, 1), dtype = "uint8")
```

Comment: Thanks! If i want to create a 3 channels RGB format iamge.  is this correct? img = np.zeros((500,500, 3), dtype = "unit8")

Comment: I tested it. Correct! Thank you Saransh!